# Finding Average Treatment Effects through R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to determine the average treatment effect of a data set. The data set already has the outcome for each unit both under treatment and under control. How can we find the effect through coding in R?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your dataset is dt, the outcome is called y and the treatment is t.
If you run `lm(data=dt, y~.)`, the coefficient for t (beta) should be your ATE.